# Form focus lost in colorbox

Tags: forms, focus, colorbox

I have a problem in my Drupal website.
I'm loading a subscription form with Colorbox, but the form focus is lost. Example is available at http://luchshieceni.ru/

```
window.jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.colorbox5').colorbox({open:true, inline:true, href:'div#content5'});
});
```

And here is the form

```
<form class="sr-box" method="post" action="https://smartresponder.ru/subscribe.html" target="_blank" name="SR_form_63724_75">    
<input type="text" name="field_name_first" class="form-txt" value="Ваше имя" onfocus="value='';">
<input type="text" name="field_email" class="form-txt" value="Ваша электронная почта" onfocus="value='';">
<input type="submit" value="Подписаться" name="subscribe" id="" class="sub-btn">                    
        </form>
```

Could You please try to help me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I followed your advice on Drupal forum (double post of the same question), and yes, it fixed my problem as well. I had:

```
$(popup).colorbox({rel:'nofollow', preloading:false, open:true, inline:true, href:popup, scalePhotos:false, iframe:true, arrowKey:false, transition:"none", slideshow:false });
```

Fixed it with:

```
$.colorbox({rel:'nofollow', preloading:false, open:true, inline:true, href:popup, scalePhotos:false, iframe:true, arrowKey:false, transition:"none", slideshow:false });
```

The jquery selector CAN'T be the same as a href.

This is very obscure, and not documented anywhere. And causes major problems. So I hope it helps someone.